# Strapi email validation is not working when registering users from admin console

Tags: content-management-system, strapi, email-validation

I am using strapi for my user management and when I register user using register api, I am getting email validation into the user’s inbox, but when I add users from the admin console(*Admin Panel*) user is not getting any email validation mails.(*Even when I register the user to be unconfirmed.*)

Answer (score 0):

The registration process send the confirmation e-mail for you.

> After having registered, if you have set Enable email confirmation to
> ON, the user will receive a confirmation link by email. The user has
> to click on it to validate his/her registration.

There is an endpoint in the user permissions plugin for you to trigger the e-mail confirmation sending: `POST /api/auth/send-email-confirmation`. Don't forget to enable it for the public role.